# Verification required for word press site

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, gmail

I have no experience with this and I'm in need of major help.  I have a word press website that I am trying to connect a gmail account to. So that the contact form gets sent to a gmail address. I got it all set up and it is telling me I need verification.  This is only being used for my word press website. Probably very few users, not a business.  Can I get around the verification process or not?

Comment: If a vendor requires some form of verification, why do you think you can bypass it? There would be no point as the bypass would just go onto the Internet for all to see. Tip: Do not use a regular user Gmail account with a website.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You would need an OAuth Consent Screen for your Project.

You can refer to this [blog post](https://wpforms.com/how-to-securely-send-wordpress-emails-using-gmail-smtp/) on how you can connect a Gmail account on your Wordpress site

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).